# Ferromagnet Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, ferromagnetism

How to derive ferromagnet Lagrangian from the Heisenberg model: $H=-J_{ij}S_i S_j$ ?
I understand how to obtain potential energy term, but it is not clear how to get "kinetic energy".
\begin{equation}
 L=\int d^2 x\frac{\rho}{2} \left[ \frac{(\partial_t \theta)^2}{v^2}-(\nabla \theta)^2\right]
\end{equation}

Comment: What is $theta$, $v$ and $\rho$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only get an equation with a second-order  time derivative for an antiferromagnet. If you have feromagnet there is only a first time derivative and you get a Landau-Lifshitz equation rather than a conventional wave equation. Deriving the antiferromagnetic equation is tricky.  See F. D. M. Haldane, Phys. Lett. 93A, 464 (1983).

Comment: Yes, thank you! I have already realized that the spectrum is linear so it is certainly not a Lagrangian for a ferromagnet. For those who are interested in deriving ferromagnet Lagrangian from path integral formulation see Altland and Simons.